# How to use the printf function?

Tags: c++, printf

I have a quick question about the `printf` function in c++.

How do I put this for loop onto the screen with the `printf` function?

```
for (int count = 0; count < numberOfEmployees; count++) {
    cout << employees[count].name << " \t" << employees[count].title << " \t" <<
                                                gross << "\t" << tax << "\t" << net << "\n";
}
```

So, I need to take out the `cout` and put in a call to `printf`.

It has to look like this, but without the dots:

Weekly Payroll:

### Name       ..             Title ...      Gross...    Tax...     Net

Ebenezer ....      Partner....    250.00......   62.25 .... 187.75

Bob Cratchit           Clerk ......      15.00 .........   2.00 ......  13.00

Comment: depends on the types of name, title, gross, tax, and net.....which is why streaming is much nicer.  Not quite sure why you want to use printf.

Comment: What type are of your variables? printf requires the type to be specified

Comment: Please learn the difference between a `command` and a `function`. `printf` is a **function**. If you're programming in C++, you should learn the terminology. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
printf("%s \t%s \t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
            employees[count].name, 
            employees[count].title, 
            gross, tax, net);
```

assuming name and title are c style strings,  and gross, tax,net are ints,  most likely none of them are those types....but gives you the feel for it.  the printf documentation gives a guide for printing out the various basic types.

Answer (score 0):

The idea w/ printf is that you have a "format string" with placeholders to be filled in by supplied values.  In your case, the format string might look like "%s \t%s \t%f\t%f\t%f\n", where each placeholder starts w/ a % followed by a specification of how to interpret the supplied value (for example, s means a string and f means a float).  There are a lot more options than that (things like field sizes, # of decimal places, left-or-right alignment), but that's the basic idea.

Comment: To get a floating-point number to print w/ 2 decimal places, you'd use %1.2f (the 1 is the field size, which is probably too small, but you can replace it with what you need).